# Powershell - Match condition for three or more values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use `-match` to check if check a string matches one of the three values

```
if ($string -match "something")
{
    # Statement is True
}
else {
    # Statement is False
}
```

is there a way i can check if a string matches three values, like

`$string -match 'something' or 'anything' or 'nothing'`

Comment: the simplest would be `-match 'ThingOne|ThingTwo|ThingThree'`. you can also simply add more tests with `-and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to a true RegEx match (`'something'-match 'thing' #true`), then you can add options by using an appropriate RegEx, in this case by using the pipe `|` to delimit.

Here is a reference (with tester): [RegEx Strom](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

If you need to match the whole value, use `^` and `$`, remember to escape `$` if needed (with a backtick).  This is really only good option is you are using other RegEx expressions (e.g. `'$som.+ing$'`).

If you just need to do exact matches, contains is the best options.  You look to see if the array contains the value you are looking for.  As the code below demonstrates, it does not match partials:

```
$string = 'red'
$a = 're'
$b='b'
$c='c'
$a2 = 'red'


#RegEx matching any
$string -match "$a|$b|$c"  # true

#RegEx matching any, in whole
$string -match "^$a`$|^$b`$|^$c`$" #false

#No Regex.   'Re' does not match 'Red'
$a,$b,$c -contains $string # false

#No Regex.  'red' matches 'red'
$a2,$b,$c -contains $string #true -icontains and -ccontains for express case insensitivity and sensitivity
```

Answer (score 0):

The order is the issue you want the variable to be tested against the constant this way and then you will receive the proper output. Though `-contains` may be a better option considering it looks like you are looking for a boolean result as opposed to the matching string being outputted. Either way you can use the example below and decide if you want to change the `-match` to a `-contains`:

```
$prediction = 'something', 'anything', 'nothing'

if ($prediction -match $string)
{
    # Statement is True
}
else {
    # Statement is False
}
```

Comment: 'or' is incorrect.  You can use commas to create an array, however this still uses RegEx matching, so $string = 'thing' would return true, which seems not be the desired result.

Comment: @Graham my bad I copied the line from the original post and I didn't catch the syntax error (it's been a long day). If you use `-contains` this will avoid the possibility of substring matching and will come back with only true or false if the entire string object matches though it ignores case sensitivity so "Anything" and "anything" will both come back true.